# Why is this highly iterative code faster than less iteration using a dictionary (js obbject really...)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, iteration

This question is specific to the hacker rank problem [Largest Permutation](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/largest-permutation/problem?isFullScreen=true)

I wrote a solution in javascript that works for most cases (A), but there are some select test cases where it times out. Ok... so then it must not be very efficient. I found someone else's solution to the problem (B) which is highly iterative. This loops through the given array at least once total, and then through the rest of the array at least K times. This seems very inefficient to me but this approach did not cause a timeout and I can't figure out why that is... one of these seems to be A: O(n) vs B: O(n^2) in my analysis but I guess im wrong... so I am asking here to see if anyone can help me figure out why this is or what the correct algorithm speed analysis is

These code snippets are the function body of a function that takes `arr` as an argument

A) My solution

```
    const indices = {}
    arr.forEach((n,i) => {
        indices[n] = i
    })
    
    let count = 0
    
    while(count < k){
        // swap to earliest index (count)
        const targetValue = arr.length - count
        const targetIndex = indices[targetValue]
    
        let tmp = arr[count]
        
       
        arr[count] = arr[targetIndex]
        arr[targetIndex] = tmp
        
        //update indices
        indices[targetValue] = count
        indices[tmp] = targetIndex
        
        
        count++
    }
    
    return arr
```

B) an alternative that to me should be slower but seems to be faster...

```
    let n = arr.length 
    for(var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if( k > 0) {
            var max = i;
            for(var j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
                if(arr[j] > arr[max])
                    max = j;
            }
            if(max != i) {
                var temp = arr[max];
                arr[max] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
                k--;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return arr
```

Comment: the problem constraints allow k to be much larger than n

Comment: Please also quote the hackerrank problem, do not just link it.

Answer (score 2):

There are these issues with your implementation:

1. When `k` is larger than `arr.length`, then the `arr.length - count` will become 0 or less and thus `targetValue` will be a value that is not in the array. And so `targetIndex` will be `undefined`.
2. Your loop represents O(), and as  can be *much* larger than , this can make a huge difference in running time.
3. When the swap is a none-operation because the value happens to *already* be in its optimal position, then `count` is still incremented, reducing the number of *actual* swaps that are done.

Not an issue, but a `for` loop seems more appropriate here than a `while`.

Here is a correction of your main loop:

```
    for (let count = 0; count < k && count < arr.length; count++) {
        const targetValue = arr.length - count
        if (arr[count] != targetValue) { // target not at optimal index?
            // swap to earliest index (count)
            const targetIndex = indices[targetValue]
        
            let tmp = arr[count]
            arr[count] = arr[targetIndex]
            arr[targetIndex] = tmp
            
            //update indices
            indices[targetValue] = count
            indices[tmp] = targetIndex
        } 
        else k++; // Allow one more swap, as this was a no-op
    }
```